# Strange phenomenon about imagelist of treeview in C# application

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, imagelist

I recently used treeview component to implement my html editor.The compiler I used is Visual Studio Community 2017.

I use imagelist to set the images of  treenodes of a treeview.
when the treenode is selected , it will shows a paper with a pen at the treenode. 
When the treenode is not selected, it will shows a paper without a pen at treenode.

My codes used in my appliation:

```
enum ImageList : int { Blank, BlankWithPen, Document, DocumentWithPen, DocumentWithLock, Locked }

TreeView1.SelectedNode.ImageIndex = (int)ImageList.Blank;
TreeView1.SelectedNode.SelectedImageIndex = (int)ImageList.BlankWithPen;
```

Images used in Imagelist[image: 1]

Image without a extra line at treenode[image: 2]

The phenomenon I encountered is that the images are showing at the treenode with a extra line.

Image with a extra line at treenode[image: 3]

This phenomenon appears more obviously ,after I coded and complied the program  several time and run it.

While I found this phenomenon , I tried to fix it. And I had checked for these origial images , there are no border around these images.

So, I removed all the images of the imagelist , and then reload the images to imagelist again, after recomplied the program without changing anything and run , this phenomenon disappeared.

This phonomenon appeared over and over again, when I made some small modifications serveral time. and can be fixed by reloading images to Imagelist again.

Obviously, this problem is not about coding.

I would like to know why this phenomenon will happen, how to fix this problem permanently ?

Comment: If you are using WPF, then you might use a program called Snoop https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/
It injects itself into the visual tree of your program. Then you might try reproducing the bug and using snoop to turn ui elements on / off inside of your visual tree. That will allow you to understand which control produces a line.

Comment: @netaholic  Sorry, I didn't mention that I used winform to develope this application in C#. Thanks for your comments anyway.

Comment: Hello , Is there any engineer from microsoft team who dedicated to Visual Stuido can comment on this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I put images into Resources of Properties , and reload images to imageList instead.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ......
        ImageList1.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.imagesBlank);
        ImageList1.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.imagesBlankWithPen);
        ImageList1.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.imagesDocument);
        ImageList1.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.imagesDocumentWithPen);
        ImageList1.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.Lock);
        ImageList1.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.imagesDocumentwithLock);
        ......
    }
```